# random.randint not generating random values

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I am working on importing `random` in Python 2.7. I would like for this code to generate two random cards. The current code does not generate random cards. If I request cards (9,11) the code generates cards (9,J) totaling to 19. There is nothing random about the output.

```
def blackjack(A,B):
   print "Welcome to Blackjack!"
   print "Your cards are",name[A-1],"&",name[B-1]
   total = value[A-1] + value[B-1]
   print "Your card total is",total

import random
A = random.randint(1,13)
B = random.randint(1,13)


name = ('A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K')
value = (11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)
```

example output:

```
>>> blackjack(9,11)
Welcome to Blackjack!
Your cards are 9 & J
Your card total is 19
```

Comment: Well, obviously if you always call your function with the arguments 9 and 11, it's always going to use the values 9 and 11. You need to actually use those random numbers you're generating.

Comment: I tried it with several number combos:

Comment: blackjack(1,10)
Welcome to Blackjack!
Your cards are A & 10
Your card total is 21
>>> blackjack(6,11)
Welcome to Blackjack!
Your cards are 6 & J
Your card total is 16
>>> blackjack(3,7)
Welcome to Blackjack!
Your cards are 3 & 7
Your card total is 10

Comment: Pass A and B to your function: blackjack(A, B)

Comment: Parameter names, `A` and `B` in your function are arbitrary. You can make them up to be whatever you want as long as you sue them properly inside your function. You don't match them to variables outside the fucntion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused between defining a function and calling it and how parameters work.

```
def blackjack(A,B):
   print "Welcome to Blackjack!"
   print "Your cards are",name[A-1],"&",name[B-1]
   total = value[A-1] + value[B-1]
   print "Your card total is",total
```

In your function `A` and `B` are place holders. They will be replaced by whatever you put in the parenthesis. Due to scoping your function doesn't know anything about `A` and `B` defined outside of it.

[Scoping](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/) is how Python knows which variables to use. A simple example of it in action can be seen here:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> def bar():
    a = 5   
>>> a
10
```

The `a` inside the function doesn't affect the one outside. The reverse is true in your function. The `A` outrside the function doesn't affect the inside *unless you pass it as a parameter*.

Try this:

```
blackjack(random.randint(1,13), random.randint(1,13))
```

And see what you get.

You can read some more about how functions work [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I will do additional research.